# How to render a CheckboxInput from a ModelForm of a OneToOneField referring to BooleanFields?

Tags: django, django-forms

Given the following models in *models.py*:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email_address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    preferences = models.OneToOneField("Preferences")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % self.name

class Preferences(models.Model):
    likes_hugging = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    despises_men = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now the following form in *forms.py*...

```
class PreferencesModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ("preferences",)
```

... produces the following result:

[image: form1]

But **how do I get the following result instead**?

[image: form2]

Answer (score 0):

you need to override the default widget. Like this:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, Textarea
from myapp.models import Author

class AuthorForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ('name', 'title', 'birth_date')
        widgets = {
            'name': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

You can read the full docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets) . The problem is that are you using the `PreferencesModelForm` correctly? The model should be `Preferences`. If you really trying to made the form for `Profile` model with `preferences`field, you can use inline formsets. You can read it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Radio instead of a checkbox in your case, since you have a OneToOne relation.

Just add to your form:

```
widgets = {
        'preferences': forms.RadioSelect(),
    }
```

PS: this question is from last year, I hope you have solved it :) I came here from google and hope to help people in the same situation.